# How can I add a ಠ symbol into my C++ output

Tags: c++, unicode, console-application, symbols

I am writing a program for school, and want to include an Easter Egg with the look of disapproval (ಠ_ಠ), however, I do not know what classes in C++ support this character. I would assume this character be included in unicode, but I am not sure how to use that to output into a console application.

If anyone could help me out with this, I would appreciate it. Thanks

Comment: Note: The Windows console cannot display this character without some major tricks, that involves changing the settings and font of the console itself, that can't be done by the program.

Comment: On Vista+, there is [`SetCurrentConsoleFontEx()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686200.aspx).

Answer (score 2):

Well you need to enable Unicode for your application. 
For MSVC you can use _setmode(_fileno(stdout), _O_U16TEXT); at the start of your main. 
But for mingw this is a bit more difficult, see [here](http://sourceforge.net/apps/trac/mingw-w64/wiki/Unicode%20apps).

To actually print it you can use the [character code](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0ca0/index.htm) and use wcout but be wary!

From: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/cout/

> A program should not mix output operations on cout with output operations on wcout (or with other wide-oriented output operations on stdout): Once an output operation has been performed on either, the standard output stream acquires an orientation (either narrow or wide) that can only be safely changed by calling freopen on stdout.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `\u0CA0`, that's the Unicode code for this eye thing. Here's a live example:

```
int main() {
    cout << "hi \u0CA0_\u0CA0";
    return 0;
}
```

https://ideone.com/QBFtsM

Although IDEOne supports unicode (as in, I can just paste `ಠ`) so I'm not sure if that will work for you. Let me know.

Comment: better use `std::wcout`

Comment: Instead of the desired result, it displays ?_?

Comment: @user2255853 What compiler do you use?

Comment: Microsoft Visual Studio Express 2013

Comment: @user2255853 I don't have 2013, but look for something similar to: Project Properties -> General -> Project Defaults -> Character Set. When you get there, turn on Multi-Byte Character Set (Unicode)

Comment: Ok, so I looked it up. Apparently they changed the system, so I will have to do more research into how now. Or just use java

Comment: @user2255853 `Or just use java` oh, the desperation. I see it clearly. Just google "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 enable unicode."